# refrence of hadith telling evil eye overtakes qaddar?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, dua, uloom-al-hadith

What is refrence of hadith ,whose approximate meaning is as follow:

"“The evil eye is real, and if anything were to overtake the divine decree (al-qadar) it would be the evil eye.”

Also please share refrence of dua mentioned in hadith:
"A’oodhu bi kalimaat-Illaah it-taamah min kulli shaytaanin wa haammah wa min kulli ‘aynin laammah"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### About Your First Question:

The exact hadeeth wording and its reference:

**Muslim, Ahmad, and al-Tirmidhi narrated from Ibn ‘Abbas that the Prophet** (*peace and blessings of Allah be upon him*) said:

> “The evil eye is real and if anything were to overtake the divine decree, it would be the evil eye. When you are asked to take a bath (to provide a cure) from the influence of the evil eye, you should take a bath.”

[Arabic Source](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/20954/%D8%AD%D9%82%D9%8A%D9%82%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%82-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87%D8%A7-%D9%88%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A7) — [English Source](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/20954/the-evil-eye-and-protection-against-it)

### About Your Second Question:

The reference of the hadeeth you proposed with its meaning:

> “A’oodhu bi kalimaat-Illaah it-taamah min kulli shaytaanin wa haammah
>   wa min kulli ‘aynin laammah"

**It means**: I seek refuge in the perfect words of Allaah from every devil and vermin and from every envious eye.

*Narrated by al-Bukhaari (3191) from the hadeeth of Ibn ‘Abbaas.*

[Youtube Source](https://youtu.be/9mzk4vi-tNA?t=283)

The video starts at 4:43 (*already set*) and ends at 6:05